How to solve Lagrange optimal control problem whose cost is independent of control?
I would like to solve an optimal control problem of the form
$$
\inf_{u : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}_+} \int_0^1 L(x(t), t) \, dt \qquad \text{subject to} \qquad \dot{x}(t) = u(t) 
$$
where $L(x, t)$ is a continuous function so that $\forall t \in [0, 1]$, the map $x \mapsto L(x, t)$ is strictly convex. I'm hoping to solve this problem for a complicated choice of $L(x, t)$, but for the sake of illustrating my confusion, consider
$$
L(x, t) = (x-t)^2
$$
for which it is easy to see that $u(t) = 1$ is the optimal control. How could I prove this using e.g. the solution to HJB equation? In this case it reads:
$$
V_t(x, t) =\inf_{u \in \mathbb{R}_+} \left\{ L(x, t) + u V_x(x, t) \right\} = L(x, t) + \begin{cases}
-\infty & V_x(x, t) < 0 \\ 
0 & V_x(x, t) > 0 \\ 
\text{anything} & V_x(x, t) = 0
\end{cases}
$$
and I do not know how to interpret the right hand side, which seems to be degenerate. What should I do?

This is typically handled via introducing a Lagrange multiplier for the constraint. See these posts and the linked pages for relevant discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12486/calculus-of-variations-and-lagrange-multipliers https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529416/calculus-of-variations-lagrange-multipliers https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279518/constrained-variational-problems-intuition
